# Replace sequence of bytes in binary file

Tags: c#, replace, byte, binaryfiles

What is the best method to replace sequence of bytes in binary file to the same length of other bytes? The binary files will be pretty large, about 50 mb and should not be loaded at once in memory.

Update: I do not know location of bytes which needs to be replaced, I need to find them first.

Comment: open file in write mode, move pointer to location of old bytes, write new bytes.

Comment: How do you know the exact position of the bytes to modify? Is it a fix offset?

Answer (score 24):

Assuming you're trying to replace a *known section* of the file.

- Open a `FileStream` with read/write access
- Seek to the right place
- Overwrite existing data

Sample code coming...

```
public static void ReplaceData(string filename, int position, byte[] data)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        stream.Position = position;
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

If you're effectively trying to do a binary version of a `string.Replace` (e.g. "always replace bytes { 51, 20, 34} with { 20, 35, 15 } then it's rather harder. As a quick description of what you'd do:

- Allocate a buffer of at least the size of data you're interested in
- Repeatedly read into the buffer, scanning for the data
- If you find a match, seek back to the right place (e.g. `stream.Position -= buffer.Length - indexWithinBuffer;` and overwrite the data

Sounds simple so far... but the tricky bit is if the data *starts* near the end of the buffer. You need to remember all *potential* matches and how far you've matched so far, so that if you get a match when you read the *next* buffer's-worth, you can detect it.

There are probably ways of avoiding this trickiness, but I wouldn't like to try to come up with them offhand :)

EDIT: Okay, I've got an idea which might help...

- Keep a buffer which is at least twice as big as you need
- Repeatedly:

  - Copy the *second* half of the buffer into the first half
  - Fill the second half of the buffer from the file
  - Search throughout the *whole* buffer for the data you're looking for

That way at some point, if the data is present, it will be completely within the buffer.

You'd need to be careful about where the stream was in order to get back to the right place, but I think this should work. It would be trickier if you were trying to find *all* matches, but at least the first match should be reasonably simple...

Comment: I forgot to indicate in my original question what I do not know position of replace bytes.

Comment: @Tomas: So is my final sentence a reasonable description of what you're after?

Comment: @Jon, sorry I forgot to indicate that. We should find first sequence of bytes in files and then replace them. I know that it is hard to do and I have googled without any luck. So posted question here.

Comment: @Tomas: Okay, I've given a description of roughly how you'd go about it.

Comment: @Jon read by chunks data is good idea but as you pointed out, how to deal with sequence of bytes if they will be in separated chunks?

Comment: @Tomas: As I say, by remembering *potential* matches, i.e. where you've detected that the end of the chunk contains the *start* of the data you're looking for.

Comment: @Tomas: See my next edit - I think I've come up with a scheme which shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: @Jon Thank you, I got it, will test and mark question as answered.

Comment: @Tomas: Sorry not to provide complete code. It's going to be fiddly :(

Comment: Thank you again for idea. I have build the method, you may find at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536400/replace-sequence-of-strings-in-binary-file

Answer (score 6):

My solution :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Copy data from a file to an other, replacing search term, ignoring case.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="originalFile"></param>
    /// <param name="outputFile"></param>
    /// <param name="searchTerm"></param>
    /// <param name="replaceTerm"></param>
    private static void ReplaceTextInBinaryFile(string originalFile, string outputFile, string searchTerm, string replaceTerm)
    {
        byte b;
        //UpperCase bytes to search
        byte[] searchBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(searchTerm.ToUpper());
        //LowerCase bytes to search
        byte[] searchBytesLower = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(searchTerm.ToLower());
        //Temporary bytes during found loop
        byte[] bytesToAdd = new byte[searchBytes.Length];
        //Search length
        int searchBytesLength = searchBytes.Length;
        //First Upper char
        byte searchByte0 = searchBytes[0];
        //First Lower char
        byte searchByte0Lower = searchBytesLower[0];
        //Replace with bytes
        byte[] replaceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(replaceTerm);
        int counter = 0;
        using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(originalFile)) {
            //input length
            long srcLength = inputStream.Length;
            using (BinaryReader inputReader = new BinaryReader(inputStream)) {
                using (FileStream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(outputFile)) {
                    using (BinaryWriter outputWriter = new BinaryWriter(outputStream)) {
                        for (int nSrc = 0; nSrc < srcLength; ++nSrc)
                            //first byte
                            if ((b = inputReader.ReadByte()) == searchByte0
                                || b == searchByte0Lower) {
                                bytesToAdd[0] = b;
                                int nSearch = 1;
                                //next bytes
                                for (; nSearch < searchBytesLength; ++nSearch)
                                    //get byte, save it and test
                                    if ((b = bytesToAdd[nSearch] = inputReader.ReadByte()) != searchBytes[nSearch]
                                        && b != searchBytesLower[nSearch]) {
                                        break;//fail
                                    }
                                    //Avoid overflow. No need, in my case, because no chance to see searchTerm at the end.
                                    //else if (nSrc + nSearch >= srcLength)
                                    //    break;

                                if (nSearch == searchBytesLength) {
                                    //success
                                    ++counter;
                                    outputWriter.Write(replaceBytes);
                                    nSrc += nSearch - 1;
                                }
                                else {
                                    //failed, add saved bytes
                                    outputWriter.Write(bytesToAdd, 0, nSearch + 1);
                                    nSrc += nSearch;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                                outputWriter.Write(b);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("ReplaceTextInBinaryFile.counter = " + counter);
    }
```

Comment: Worked nicely for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use my *BinaryUtility* to search and replace one or more bytes without loading the entire file into memory like this:

```
var searchAndReplace = new List<Tuple<byte[], byte[]>>() 
{
    Tuple.Create(
        BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt32)0xDEADBEEF),
        BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt32)0x01234567)),
    Tuple.Create(
        BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt32)0xAABBCCDD),
        BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16)0xAFFE)),
};
using(var reader =
    new BinaryReader(new FileStream(@"C:\temp\data.bin", FileMode.Open)))
{
    using(var writer =
        new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(@"C:\temp\result.bin", FileMode.Create)))
    {
        BinaryUtility.Replace(reader, writer, searchAndReplace);
    }
}
```

*BinaryUtility* code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public static class BinaryUtility
{
    public static IEnumerable<byte> GetByteStream(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        const int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer;
        do
        {
            buffer = reader.ReadBytes(bufferSize);
            foreach (var d in buffer) { yield return d; }
        } while (bufferSize == buffer.Length);
    }

    public static void Replace(BinaryReader reader, BinaryWriter writer, IEnumerable<Tuple<byte[], byte[]>> searchAndReplace)
    {
        foreach (byte d in Replace(GetByteStream(reader), searchAndReplace)) { writer.Write(d); }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<byte> Replace(IEnumerable<byte> source, IEnumerable<Tuple<byte[], byte[]>> searchAndReplace)
    {
        foreach (var s in searchAndReplace)
        {
            source = Replace(source, s.Item1, s.Item2);
        }
        return source;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<byte> Replace(IEnumerable<byte> input, IEnumerable<byte> from, IEnumerable<byte> to)
    {
        var fromEnumerator = from.GetEnumerator();
        fromEnumerator.MoveNext();
        int match = 0;
        foreach (var data in input)
        {
            if (data == fromEnumerator.Current)
            {
                match++;
                if (fromEnumerator.MoveNext()) { continue; }
                foreach (byte d in to) { yield return d; }
                match = 0;
                fromEnumerator.Reset();
                fromEnumerator.MoveNext();
                continue;
            }
            if (0 != match)
            {
                foreach (byte d in from.Take(match)) { yield return d; }
                match = 0;
                fromEnumerator.Reset();
                fromEnumerator.MoveNext();
            }
            yield return data;
        }
        if (0 != match)
        {
            foreach (byte d in from.Take(match)) { yield return d; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static void BinaryReplace(string sourceFile, byte[] sourceSeq, string targetFile, byte[] targetSeq)
    {
        FileStream sourceStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFile);
        FileStream targetStream = File.Create(targetFile);

        try
        {
            int b;
            long foundSeqOffset = -1;
            int searchByteCursor = 0;

            while ((b=sourceStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
            {
                if (sourceSeq[searchByteCursor] == b)
                {
                    if (searchByteCursor == sourceSeq.Length - 1)
                    {
                        targetStream.Write(targetSeq, 0, targetSeq.Length);
                        searchByteCursor = 0;
                        foundSeqOffset = -1;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        if (searchByteCursor == 0)
                        {
                            foundSeqOffset = sourceStream.Position - 1;
                        }

                        ++searchByteCursor;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (searchByteCursor == 0)
                    {
                        targetStream.WriteByte((byte) b);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        targetStream.WriteByte(sourceSeq[0]);
                        sourceStream.Position = foundSeqOffset + 1;
                        searchByteCursor = 0;
                        foundSeqOffset = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            sourceStream.Dispose();
            targetStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
```