# Replace sequence of bytes in binary file C++

Tags: c++

I would like to replace sequence of bytes in file before I will run it, so for example 3B 01 40 3F to 00 00 10 3F.
I was looking for the solution in Google but there are only C# answers.

[Replace sequence of bytes in binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525660/replace-sequence-of-bytes-in-binary-file)

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: So what have you done so far? To me, this is not a terribly hard problem to solve - just read the file byte by byte, compare with your sequence [you may need a statemachine to track where in the sequence you are] and write the modified bytes out to an output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# answer should work here as well.

```
void replace(long pos, std::string filename, std::string replacement)
{
   std::ofstream out(filename.c_str());
   out.seekp(pos);

   out.write(replacement.c_str(), replacement.size());
}
```

Comment: I think this solution creates a zero filled file except for the replacement bytes which are at the end of the file.