# Replace bytes in a file based on positions

Tags: c#, file, byte

In C# I want to replace example bytes number 200-5000 by an array/stream of 30000 bytes inside a file, the numbers are just for example, the sizes may vary, I could be replacing a section with either more or less bytes than the size of the section.

I have checked this question:
[Replace sequence of bytes in binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525660/replace-sequence-of-bytes-in-binary-file)

It only explains how to override a fixed-sized section and will overwrite data after if the byte array length is bigger than original section and will leave old bytes in place if the section to be replaced is bigger than the new bytes.

Higher performance and not having to read the entire file into memory would be preferred, but anything goes.

I would need this to work both on windows and linux.

Comment: With windows you have to read file and then write.  Windows is not designed for read/write.  Get into the file structure you can modify sectors to speed up the modifying but that is messy.  If you want to add data then use a List<byte> rather than an array.

Comment: Could you use MemoryMappedFiles? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files

Comment: @jdweng It needs to work on linux, I will update the question

Comment: I assume you are using Core. The code should on Linux the same as Windows.  The Net library doesn't change on Linux and doesn't take advantage of opening a file for read/write on Linux.  Using c++ you can do following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reading-and-writing-files?view=msvc-170